# After 3 Years of PhD - problems with University registration - Fight or apply for another PhD

Tags: phd, university, deadlines

The Main problem is university registration as the process is vital to enroll as a PhD student, so that I can submit my thesis and defend it. Administrative issues here in Germany have prevented me from completing the registration process because I am an overseas student and some issues to do with deadlines.

Some good news are have published three papers as first author in leading journals and written the thesis work as well.

Is it a good idea to dump this registration process and take another PhD or should I apply for industry jobs? Note that I am not committed to staying in academia.

Comment: Your question confuses me. Are you asking whether you should give up on your half-written thesis based on what sounds like a formality? If so, the answer is **no**, but then I am also not sure why you are even asking.

Comment: I am still not a student in the University (because of registration issues) after 3 years of PhD program. So can i give up the process and get a job in industry section (without the PhD). Thanks for your help

Comment: So you are saying you did not manage to get the registration process done in three years? That *does* sound serious, but the we will certainly need more information about what the actual problem is (immigration issues, legal issues, lacking support from faculty, etc.) to give advice. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What are the administrative issues that prevent you from enrolling as a student?

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered without more information.  What has been happening over the last three years (regarding interaction with faculty, having an advisor, status as a student, funding, use of university facilities, etc.) and why?  What do faculty members and administrators at the university say about the prospects of getting a Ph.D.?  Without understanding what's going on here, it's hard to say anything constructive.

Comment: I deleted my comments because I'm lost here. OP is in a 'PhD program' but does not have an advisor and is not a registered student, he's not a freelance researcher neither. I have never heard of such a situation although it's apparently not surprising to some.

Comment: @Jigg: Being a grad student and being a researcher in Germany are parallel processes; see my response below.

Comment: I suppose the OP has posted a confusing message due to not being proficient in English, but he's not aware of it. I vote for close, in this form.

Comment: @QuoraFeans: For someone in the German system, the situation can be _exactly_ as described. There's no need to close.

Comment: @aeismail: "Administrative issues", "prevented me from completing the registration process", and " some issues to do with deadlines" is not terribly specific. We could imagine many things here. Was he caught plagiarizing from the Internet (like many other German PhD?), has he missed a deadline by several months? This is not a concrete problem the OP is facing, or, at least, he is not explaining his concrete problem.

Comment: @QuoraFeans: Administrative procedures in Germany academia are arcane and byzantine, particularly where foreign degrees are involved. More likely than not, some forms weren't submitted on time, and now the department or university is giving him grief about it.

Comment: @aeismail: I have no doubt you could be right, but since we don't know exactly what happened, nor whether there is a problem that can be corrected, the question remains meaningless. A future user of the site won't be able to know whether this question applies to his situation. Equally, the advice that you gave, (talking to his advisor) might or might not be the most appropriate. Maybe the relationship with him is already strained, maybe it's not his business, or it's not within his power to solve the problem.

Answer (score 18):

For the benefit of the wider audience, a little background into the German PhD system is in order.

- Researchers after the master's level are hired as *Wissenschaftliche Mitarbeiter* (researchers, literally "academic personnel"), and work for the individual research groups as half- or full-time employees, with the commensurate salary and benefits.
- In parallel, students are expected to register as doctoral students (*Zulassung*). Such a process will typically involve some classwork for international students, particularly those studying in engineering fields (and those with degrees other than the area they're now studying). One of the forms to be filled out in this process is the *Betreuungsbestätigung*, which is a commitment by the signer to be the candidate's advisor.

Normally, deadlines are deadlines; however, if there are mitigating circumstances, many departments will allow the advisor to petition for exceptions to be made. Given that you've made good research progress, it would seem reasonable that your advisor would want to ensure that you get your PhD. So, before doing anything else, **talk to your advisor.**

Comment: Your answer makes the question clearer. The first category seems to be some sort of post-master research staff. The second category seems to be a PhD program. In the case of the 1st category, I assume the OP has a supervisor (or similar role). Does he have an advisor in that case? Your answer seems to suggest that he does have an advisor. Would you clarify?

Comment: That's done in the second step. See above revision.

Answer (score 2):

If possible try to stick with finishing the PhD. You are almost there.

Try to find some legal advisor to help you with the issues. Some universities may even offer free legal help and have persons acting as ombudsman.

Finding good job opportunities will not be an issue in any case.

Comment: The OP is not officially in the student list. I am not sure what _finishing the PhD_ means. If the university does not recognise the OP as a student, how and why would they offer free legal help?

Comment: Finishing means writing and defending PhD thesis. At some universities the Law cathedra, in order to give practical work for their students, offers some kind of services to public. This is for free and just to give advices&options that persons in need may pursue further.

Comment: @qoobit But it's not clear that OP has actually even _started_ a PhD.  Yeah, he's done some research and published some papers, but that doesn't make him a PhD student.

Comment: @JeffE: The OP has clearly been trying to become a PhD student, but somehow the process hasn't gone the way it's supposed to.

Comment: 'Finding good job opportunities will not be an issue in any case' on what basis can you say this?

Comment: I admit, I have no scientific proof but more of personal experience with some of PhD students I know. Positive thinking should help anyway.